# Is using readlines in Python bad code?

Tags: python

I got downvoted for an answer using file.readlines. The critic said that using readlines is crap code (along with other very rude statements).

Is it so bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `readlines` is fine. You just have to remember, that the **whole file** is stored in memory at one point.

Comment: @MYYN: Thanks, seems the most logical and unbiased to me.

Answer (score 9):

I assume that the problem was the fact that `readlines()` loads the whole file into memory, which - theoretically - can be a lot.

A lazy approach (iterating over the file and reading progressively as needed) is indeed better in terms of memory usage. Not sure about efficiency, though.

Comment: When the file is so large that a hypothetical speed difference between `readlines` and iterating it becomes significant, `readlines` propably becomes infeasible because of memory consumption.

Comment: for efficiency, the OS probably will read a few k ahead and cache it, even if you are reading line by line.

Comment: I don't really get the use case for `fp.readlines()`. If you want a list of lines you can write `list(fp)`.

Comment: @delnan: True. And that's exactly the problem. Iterating over the file however, does not get infeasible no matter the size of the file. :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, bad and bad. But it loads the whole file in memory which can be a problem, and there is a much better way:

```
 for line in file:
```

That will do the same as

```
 for line in file.xreadlines():
```

Which is a version of readlines() that doesn't read the whole file in memory. It also works in Python 3 as an added bonus, while xreadlines() doesn't.

So no matter if it's "bad" or not, there is no reason to use it, like ever. So don't. :)

Comment: You've never written algorithms that don't process input line by line? How would you write a diff algorithm?

Comment: @André Caron: Your question is confused. Try again.

Comment: There is no reason to use it except when you want to load the whole file in memory.

Comment: @Lennart: perhaps it is true in your repertory.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: There are some cases where having the whole file in memory is useful -- one example is when very fast random access is needed.

Comment: @martineau: Right, so *not* iteration then. And random access to the lines of a file? Including the line-break, which is what you get with readlines()? Nah. If you want random access to the contents of a file and it really is one entry per row, then usually you want to strip the lines too. Which means you first need to iterate over them to make the resulting list. Which again means you aren't loading the file into memory in any useful meaning. But more typically, random access to the file is either binary data, or you want to make the file into a dictionary.

Comment: Simple use case: short (couple hundred lines) text stored in a string.  User may wish to use a different string from a file based on a command line switch.  Simplest solution: replace the string with the content of the file when parsing the command line.   Easiest implementation uses readlines.  Edit: I suppose read would suffice.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. On the other hand, you can use `xreadlines` to have faster code.

Comment: BTW- "Deprecated since version 2.3: Use for line in file instead."

Comment: xreadlines has a note: Deprecated since version 2.3: Use for line in file instead.

Comment: Reference here http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#xreadlines