# Is using readlines() the better approach than creating a List?

Tags: python, list, file, io

I was reviewing some notes today and I came across this snippet of code:

```
def read_entire_file(file):
    with open(file) as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.readlines()
    print(contents)
    print(type(contents)) # I added this line
```

A quick glance and it looks like I'm overwriting a variable with each line that I'm reading, however, it creates a list, and you can verify that `contents` is a list with the `type()` method.

Compare it to this code:

```
def read_file_into_list(file):

    employees = []

    with open(file) as f_obj:
       for line in f_obj:
           employees.append(line.strip())
    print(employees)
```

Where I can see at a quick glance, I created an `employee` list and I'm reading in each line and appending to the list.

I'm aware from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533884/is-using-readlines-in-python-bad-code) that it reads the whole file into memory, but if you want to create a list from the data, which approach is better?

I like the second approach, while it's a little more code, it's clear what I'm doing, while the first approach, it isn't quite clear until you inspect it further.

Comment: I disagree. I think the first example is much more clear. `readlines()` should be pretty well known by Python programmers.

Comment: It's generally not advised to use either of the above methods in case of big files, but if you ask, I would choose first over second.

Comment: Your examples aren't quite the same.  The second example does a transformation (`line.strip()`) on each line.  If you need to do that, `employees = [line.strip() for line in f_obj]` would be more efficient than the second approach.

Comment: In general, it is (almost) always better to use a built-in method or function instead of writing your own, both for under-the-hood efficiency and for DRY and readability purposes

Comment: I think the idiomatic way is to just use `data = list(f_obj)`.  Generally, just treating the file as an iterator is the way to go, IMO

Comment: @Austin - Out of curiosity what should you use for big files? Let's assume the data is text.

Comment: For big files, you don't wait for loading *all* the lines to a list before working on it. Instead, you work on the go - Yes, I have got a line! Why should I wait!?; will work on it straight away. (Much more memory efficient).

Comment: @Austin - Comparing the second example to a list comprehension, both do the same thing and perform at the same efficient, it's just that the list comprehension is more pythonic, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A quick glance and it looks like I'm overwriting a variable with each line that I'm reading...

Why is that? Do you see the `with` as a `while`? I am used to the first one and to me at a glance it looks like just what it is: a call to `readlines()` to read the entire file in.

> Where I can see at a quick glance, I created an employee list and I'm reading in each line and appending to the `List`.

When I see explicit `for` and `while` loops that work one element or one line at a time, my first thought is, "Looks like a C++ or Java programmer who's not used to Python." It's a habit you should get out of. In Python there is oftentimes a more idiomatic approach using bulk operations, list comprehensions, or generators that avoids an old school imperative loop.

> I like the second approach, while it's a little more code, it's clear what I'm doing, while the first approach, it isn't quite clear until you inspect it further.

As a veteran Python programmer, I prefer the first one. If you want to read a file into memory you call `readlines()`. It does what it says on the tin.

That said, I would also question whether reading the entire file into memory is the right thing to do. Perhaps you should process it line by line without chewing up a whole bunch of memory. In that case the idiomatic solution is indeed a `for` loop. But not one where you simply add all the elements to a list.

```
with open(file) as f_obj:
    for line in f_obj:
        process_line(line.strip())
```

Alternatively, if stripping the whitespace is important *and* you want to read everything into memory, consider a list comprehension.

```
with open(file) as f_obj:
    employees = [line.strip() for line in f_obj]
```

Comment: In terms of efficiency, is the list comprehension approach a better than reading and adding it to a `List` (second example) or are the both the same?

Comment: Another question, using the second approach isn't necessarily wrong, it's just not the Python way, correct? More like Java or C#.

Comment: Both are roughly equal efficiency; the list comprehension may be slightly faster, I don't know. And correct, the second approach isn't wrong, just not the Python way.